# nucleo-f746zg board programming with openocd

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, openocd

I have a nucleo-144 board with stm32f746zg MCU. I'm trying to program the board with openocd, using gnu make and the makefile generated from stm32cubemx. I've added following line to my makefile to automate the flashing process:

```
flash: all
    openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f7x.cfg -c "program $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf verify reset exit"
```

The code compiles without any problem and when I type `make flash` in the terminal the result is:

```
❯ make flash
openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f7x.cfg -c "program build/my-board.elf verify reset exit"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0 (2021-11-18) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : DEPRECATED target event trace-config; use TPIU events {pre,post}-{enable,disable}
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
Info : STLINK V2J33M25 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:374B
Info : Target voltage: 3.236769
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: Cortex-M7 r0p1 processor detected
Warn : Silicon bug: single stepping may enter pending exception handler!
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: target has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f7x.cpu on 3333
Error: couldn't bind gdb to socket on port 3333: No error
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08002a18 msp: 0x20050000
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
** Programming Started **
Info : device id = 0x10016449
Info : flash size = 1024 kbytes
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
** Verified OK **
** Resetting Target **
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
shutdown command invoked
```

But the program doesn't run on the board and there's no blinking. I tried this in windows and wsl ubuntu. In both cases the results are the same. Also tried loading the binary file instead of .elf but again no luck.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is there a reason why you are using openocd?  simply to learn how?  for a nucleo board you simply copy the binary file over the virtual drive.  binary as in memory image if gnu tools it would be the output of the arm-whatever-objcopy -O binary myfile.elf myfile.bin then you copy or drag and drop myfile.bin to the virtual removable drive that mounts when you plug it in.

Comment: with openocd it woudl be some form of flash write_image erase myfile.elf

Comment: preceeded by a reset halt if needed

Comment: now loading on the board and blinking are two different things it may have loaded on the board but your program has issues and is not blinking for that reason.

Comment: if you use the drag and drop/copy method then there will be a FAIL.TXT file that indicates (without much useful information) that the load fails.

Comment: did you resolve the libusb issue?

Comment: did you try without gdb and just telnet in directly?   really cannot tell what you tried...and what debugging you did.  what program are you running did you inspect the vector table and disassembly to confirm it was built right and that it even has a chance of booting properly, etc?

Comment: Seems that my board (or the st-link part of it) is not working properly. I tried the same procedure with a custom board with f103 MCU (using another usb st-link programmer) and program loaded and executed without any problem. I tried drag and dropping binary file to the drive, but after copying the file, the drive closes and re-opens automatically and the binary file is gone. I also removed the CN4 jumpers on the st-link part of the board and used the SWD pins to power and program my custom board, but the custom board doesn't get powered up. So I think I must have broken the st-link somehow.

Comment: I didn't suspect the hardware fault because couple of days ago it was working properly. 
I want to learn openOCD and gdb in order to make my projects more portable and don't rely on specific IDEs like keil or platromio etc.
thanks for the comments by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm not sure if I should post this as an answer, but the problem wasn't either openocd or the broken hardware.

When I started the project in cubemx, I **initialized the default nucleo-f746zg peripherals** and for some reason (probably one of the peripherals need higher clock frequency to work properly) in clock configuration the default clock source is selected as HSE and this option [cannot be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vngdA.png). On the other hand the nucleo board doesn't come with an external oscillator and it should be soldered by the user. So after generating the code and flashing it to the board it causes an error and the program doesn't run. Although, I think  there was a block of code in clock configuration of HAL libraries that would "try" to use HSE and PLL as clock source and in case of not responding or any problem in settings, the HSI would be used as default source.

Anyway when I start the project from MCU selector in cubemx and don't use nucleo initializations, I can set the clock to HSI and everything works fine.